# Login failed for user '' when connecting to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'M trying to connect to my database (which is on the same computer) through my C# code. The problem is I keep getting the `Login failed for user " "` error...

Here's part of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hotel_Essencia
{
public partial class CheckIn : Form
{
    public CheckIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Database= HotelManagement; server= Sherissa\SQLEXPRESS";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CheckIn (@TransactionId,@GuestName,@RoomType,@RoomNo,@ReservationDate,@CheckInDate,@CheckOutDate,@NoOfDays,@NoOfAdults,@NoOfChildren),", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionId",textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestName", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomType", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReservationDate", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckInDate", textBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckOutDate", textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfDays", textBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfAdults", textBox9.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfChildren", textBox10.Text);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED SUCCESSFULLY!!");
    }

    private void CheckIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Provide User Id and Password in connection string

Comment: @Amit dont hav a user id and password

Comment: Then if you use windows authentication to log in, use Integrated Security=True

Comment: use this "Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=True"

Answer (score 4):

You need to arrange credentials in your connection string, if you don't have credentials and are working locally then you could get away with using Integrated Security:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=True;
```

When you set up a user for the database explicitly, then add the credentials accordingly:

```
User Id=username;Password=password;
```

Comment: now m getting da error Incorrect syntax near ','.  for   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You have an extra comma in your query, remove it: `@NoOfChildren),`

Comment: @arran its proper ..  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfChildren", textBox10.Text); ?... rite ?..

Comment: No, here: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CheckIn (@TransactionId,@GuestName,@RoomType,@RoomNo,@ReservationDate,@CheckInDate,@CheckOutDate,@NoOfDays,@NoOfAdults,@NoOfChildren),", con);` ...notice the extra comma here? `@NoOfChildren),", con)`...the comma after the `@NoOfChildren)`?

Comment: @Arran Incorrect syntax near ')'. n now dis error ... m sry  :( n thx for ur time :P